# Swift: glDrawElements crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I'm learning **OpenGL** on iOS by this [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0), and I want to implement everything on **swift**. So, there is some code were I'm getting crash:

Memory structures:

```
private struct Vertex {
    var Position: (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
    var Color: (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)
}

private static var Vertices = [
    Vertex(Position: (1, -1, 0) , Color: (1, 0, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (1, 1, 0)  , Color: (0, 1, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, 1, 0) , Color: (0, 0, 1, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, -1, 0), Color: (0, 0, 0, 1))
]

private static var Indices: [GLubyte] = [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
]
```

Create vertex buffers:

```
var vertexBuffer = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vertexBuffer)
glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), Vertices.size, Vertices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))

var indexBuffer = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer)
glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indexBuffer)
glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), Indices.size, Indices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
```

Setup memory offsets:

```
var positionPtr = 0
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(positionSlot), 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(strideofValue(Vertex)), &positionPtr)
var colorPtr = strideof(GLfloat) * 3
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(colorSlot), 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(strideofValue(Vertex)), &colorPtr)
```

**Crash** (Trying to draw):

```
var startPtr = 0
// EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 here!
glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count / 3), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &startPtr)
```

All shaders are compiled without any errors and `glClear()` draws well, so I suppose my problem is concerned with VBOs.

And here how I calculate size of arrays:

```
extension Array
{
    var size: Int {
        get { return self.count * strideof(Element) }
    }
}
```

UPD: I'm using OpenGLES 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had learned by you guide for amount 4 months ago. I tried to convert it from objective-c to swift until draw rectangle same below picture.
Now I run it and convert to Swift 2.1. It still work and show same image below.

[image]

**Here my code (Method setupVBOs, render and struct)**

```
// Track of all our per-vertex information (currently just color and position)
struct Vertex {
    var Position: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
    var Color: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
}

// Array with all the info for each vertex
var Vertices = [
    Vertex(Position: (1, -1, 0) , Color: (1, 0, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (1, 1, 0)  , Color: (0, 1, 0, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, 1, 0) , Color: (0, 0, 1, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, -1, 0), Color: (0, 0, 0, 1))
 ]

 // Array that gives a list of triangles to create, by specifying the 3 vertices that make up each triangle
var Indices: [GLubyte] = [
   0, 1, 2,
   2, 3, 0
]

//helper extensions to pass arguments to GL land
extension Array {
    func size () -> Int {
       return self.count * sizeofValue(self[0])
    }
}

//The best way to send data to OpenGL is through something called Vertex Buffer Objects.
func setupVBOs() {  // VBO : Vertex Buffer Objects.

    //There are two types of vertex buffer objects – one to keep track of the per-vertex data (like we have in the Vertices array), and one to keep track of the indices that make up triangles (like we have in the Indices array).
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
    glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vertexBuffer)
    glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), Vertices.count * sizeofValue(Vertices[0]), Vertices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW)) //  send the data over to OpenGL-land.

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer)
    glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indexBuffer)
    glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), Indices.count * sizeofValue(Indices[0]), Indices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
}

func render() {
    glClearColor(0, 104.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

    //glViewport(0, 0, GLint(frame.size.width), GLint(frame.size.height))
    glViewport(0, GLint(frame.size.height/2)/2, GLint(frame.size.width), GLint(frame.size.height/2))

    //  feed the correct values to the two input variables for the vertex shader – the Position and SourceColor attributes.
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), GLsizei(sizeof(Vertex)), nil)
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), GLsizei(sizeof(Vertex)), UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(Float) * 3))

    // This actually ends up calling your vertex shader for every vertex you pass in, and then the fragment shader on each pixel to display on the screen.
    glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), nil)

    _context.presentRenderbuffer(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER))
}
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you so very much! I had two mistakes here. I used `strideof` instead of `sizeof` and also the problem with pointer which was solved by using of the bitPattern. After those fixes everything works, although I don't know why :)